# Using pki::pkcs::parse_key results in error

Tags: tcl, x509, pki, tclws

I try to use tcl package pki::sign. The goal is to sign a SOAP message with a X509 certificate, using tclws.

Parsing the public key is OK :

```
pki::x509::parse_cert $publickey
```

However, parsing the private key does not work

```
pki::pkcs::parse_key $privatekey
```

It results in the following error :

```
"Expected Sequence (0x30), but got 42"
```

The certificate was provided to me as a .p12 file.
I could get the public and private key with openssl with the following commands :

Public key :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

Private key :

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out key.pem
```

Comment: I suspect that's coming out of the asn1 parser (`asn::asnGetSequence` specifically) and that it indicates that there was a `B` (`\u0042`) which was unexpected. I don't know what that means.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. It seems that asn::asnGetSequence waits for "0" as starting char and nothing else. The private key I have starts with "MII..". I saw  [here](https://github.com/tcltk/tcllib/tree/master/modules/pki) that only DES private key start with a zero. I don't understand...

Comment: There are various ways to encode a private key, for example PKCS#1/RFC 3447 (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447#page-44) and a few others, so your key might be in an encoding not recognized by the module.

Comment: The 0x30 is the ASN.1 encoding for a SEQUENCE, 0x42 is a different tag, probably an APPLICATION Tag 0x40 of an Integer. 0x02. This has a little overview of the formats for keys you might see: https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Comment: At this point, I understand that the certificate format is not supported by pki::pkcs::parse_key. I am now trying to find a solution through openssl.

Comment: Very probable, yes. If you could give a hint what kind of private key you have (e.g. DSA/RSA/ECDSA/etc. one might get a clue.)

Comment: Using the "x509" function of openssl, it indicates that Signature Algorithm is sha256WithRSAEncryption, and that Public Key Algorithm is rsaEncryption.

Comment: I did not success in signing  a SOAP message with a X509 certificate, using tclws : I did not have enough background xml canonicalization and soap signature, and not enough time to do it.  I found a solution with python, using the package pysimplesoap.